# Tracking referral traffic from Sub Domain to Primary Domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have a primary site (www.example.com) and a blog (blog.example.com). They each have their own Analytics properties with their own tracking code.

What I want to see is how much referral traffic the blog sends to the primary site. Currently I'm not seeing any referral traffic even though I have had various people visit the blog then click a link to the main site.

I read that it may be due to the fact that when you set up the account example.com is put in the Referral Exclusion List. I have since removed it from there but am still not seeing any referrals.

Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: How have you set up your tracker object's cookie domain? Is it auto or something else?

Comment: Hi, yes it is auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No, I checked today and the referral traffic is reflecting correctly. Removing the domain from the Referral Exclusion List yesterday is what must have fixed it. Perhaps I was a bit hasty in saying that it hadn't made a difference...